# Creating a barchart in using Google chart API by passing variables to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I want to create a Barchart using Google Chart API by passing Countryname and parametername to a PHP file. I'm sure the PHP file( data.php) has been working well.
My Source code for bargraph.html is like this :

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <body id="body">
<div id="content">
<form action ="" method ="">
<tr id="tableRow">
        <th valign="bottom">Select country:</th>
        <td >   
        <select name="country" id="myCountry" class="">

           <option value = "AFG">Afganistan</option>

                <option value = "TUR">Turkey</option>
               <option value = "TKM">Turkamenistan</option>
               <option value = "TUV">Tuvalu</option>
               <option value = "UGA">Uganda</option>
               <option value = "UKR">Ukraine</option>
               <option value = "ARE">UAE</option>
               <option value = "GBR">United Kingdom</option>

            </select>

        </td>
        <th valign="bottom">Select parameters:</th>
        <td >   
        <select name="indices" id="myIndices" class="">

             <option value= "foodfinal">Vulnerability on food</option>
             <option value= "waterfinal">Vulnerability on water </option>
             <option value= "ecosystemfinal">Vulnerability on ecosystem </option>
             <option value= "habitatfinal">Vulnerability on habitat </option>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <input type="button" class="action" onclick="displayGraph()" value="DisplayGraph" />
            </td>
</tr>

</form>
</div>

    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    displayGraph();
function displayGraph(){

var country = document.getElementById("myCountry").value;
var index = document.getElementById("myIndices").value;
// var countryCombo = document.getElementById("myCountry");
// var indexCombo = document.getElementById("myIndices");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "";
// document.getElementById("body").appendChild(countryCombo);
// document.getElementById("body").appendChild(indexCombo);
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(content);

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "data.php?country="+country+"&indices="+index,
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 1500, height: 700});
    }
  }


    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

While I choose the country and Parameters from two buttons and click on the displayGraph button, the Bargraph has to be displayed on the Webpage. Currently, Just after Loading the Page, there appears a bargraph with the correct values. But, as I click the displayGraph button, there is no output. How can I create a Bargraph with this approach ?

Comment: I can't speak for the rest of your code, but it looks like you're trying to access the values of your dropdowns incorrectly. Since you're already using jQuery, why not take advantage of it? Like this: `$('#myCountry').val()`. Same for your other `select` element.

Comment: @ Vch, how can I take advantage of it ?

Comment: `var country = $('#myCountry').val();`

Comment: Did you mean ( Using the above line instead of this one : var country= document.getElementById("myCountry").value;
var index = document.getElementById("myIndices").value;) ?

Comment: @ Vch, I changed the Code but the same persists again.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed: `<body>` is not a valid child of `<head>`.  Also, what is the intention behind clearing and rewriting the contents of `<body>`?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I just removed the <head> Tag.